# Entity Framework DataContext Concern - Is it getting disposed properly in my controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I've been handed some code, and in the controller class there is a property that holds the initialized database context.

```
public class MyController: Controller
{
    protected AssetManagerContext db = new AssetManagerContext("ConnectionString");
    // Actions...etc.

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
        MyAsset myAsset = db.Assets.Find(id); // Used and not disposed
        return View(myAsset);
    }
 }
```

Most of the actions use this Context without disposing it, and my concern is that the context is left open.

1. Do I need to be concerned about this context not being explicitly closed (either by .Dispose() or a using {} statement
2. If I should worry, how should I handle this situation, since the variable is part of the class and used across actions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Controller class has a method of dispose. So override that method in your controller and dispose that context.

```
protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
   base.Dispose(disposing);
   db.Dispose();
}
```

It will be called automatically after the context get completed.

Comment: Due to the high number of actions using the DB context, this seems most simple.

Answer (score 4):

It is never a good idea to leave a context open between calls to the controller.

That causes the DB connection to be held until the MyController instance is disposed by the GC.

If your controller does all of the interaction with Entity Framework (your views do not need to lazily load domain objects), the simplest pattern is

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult MyAction(...)
    {
        using (AssetManagerContext db = new AssetManagerContext("ConnectionString"))
        {
            // Do stuff
        }
    }
}
```

If your view does need to lazily load objects from the context, you can indeed hold a reference to the context object as a property of the class and implement IDisposable as suggested by @Kundan.

Comment: Well, technically it's not.  Controllers are destroyed at the end of every request, but the context won't be cleaned up until gc runs.

Comment: @MystereMan: Interesting, I did not know they were instantiated per-request.  However, that makes perfect sense.

Comment: I wouldn't say that this is the proper pattern, or at least you need to mention that lazy loading can no longer be used.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov: Why not?  When would you ever keep a context open beyond the scope of a single web request?  Certainly, you can still use lazy loading.

Comment: @EricJ. - if you pass any of the entities to the view, the context will have been destroyed, and thus lazy loading doesn't work.

Comment: @MystereMan: Ah, I see where you are coming from.  I never do that (not sure that a view should ever interact with domain objects...) so never considered that as a factor.

Comment: @EricJ., what about `return Json(someEntity);`? Not that you should ever pass domain entities to views, you should rather use view models, but I see lots of people using it. The JsonResult will be executed much after the action has finished running and the context being disposed. So when it attempts to Json serialize the entity it will throw an exception.

Comment: @EricJ. - I agree, that passing entities to the view isn't the best approach, but lots of sample code does that, so lots of people do it.  It's not recommended, but it's not necessarily wrong.

Comment: I recommend reading this http://stephenwalther.com/archive/2008/08/20/asp-net-mvc-tip-34-dispose-of-your-datacontext-or-don-t.aspx ;) Very interesting stuff.

Comment: @MystereMan: Lots of sample code (even on MSDN) doesn't dispose of IDisposable objects, either :-)  But I updated my response to reflect the valid points in the comments.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov - I'd be interested to see your approach as an answer.

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey, I'd rather use my DI framework to take care of this. I'd use an Unit of Work pattern and never actually have a concrete DBContext within my controller.

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey - I think Darin's and My approach are the same, and that's to use Dependency Injection to manage the context lifetime.

Answer (score 2):

In reality, it doesn't really matter.  As Stephen Walter [pointed out](http://stephenwalther.com/archive/2008/08/20/asp-net-mvc-tip-34-dispose-of-your-datacontext-or-don-t.aspx) when he posted a link to one of his blog entries in the comments, it isn't particularly important to cleanup a data context because ultimately, the data context does a fantastic job of managing its own connections and pooling connections.

You may have a little extra memory allocated for longer than it needs to if you don't clean it up, but it's not going to keep connections open longer than necessary.

Best practice, however, is to clean up after yourself.  Even if you know it doesn't (currently) matter.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should always explicitly release expensive resources, e.g. database connections, streams, etc. Don't rely on the framework to do this for you. Even if it does this right now, you never know if Microsoft will change this in the future, leaving you with a huge leak you probably won't find.

You can create and dispose the context in every action with a `using` block.

But to spare some code and follow the [DRY](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%E2%80%99t_repeat_yourself) principle, you can instantiate and dispose the context before and after every action by overriding the [`OnActionExecuting`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.onactionexecuting%28v=vs.108%29) and [`OnActionExecutedContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.onactionexecuted%28v=vs.108%29) respectively:

```
public class MyController: Controller
{
    protected AssetManagerContext db;

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
        MyAsset myAsset = db.Assets.Find(id); // Used and not disposed
        return View(myAsset);
    }

    protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext db) {
        base.OnActionExecuting(db);
        db = new AssetManagerContext("ConnectionString");
    }

    protected override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext db) {
        base.OnActionExecuted(db);
        db.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: That's an interesting approach.  I've never seen it before.  I think i'd probably dispose in the controllers Dispose method though.

Comment: You should't rely on the controller's dispose method to be called by the framework. You never know when MS will change the implementation. When it comes to database access it is always better to make sure the resources are released explicitly.

Comment: I don't think it's reasonable to expect that MS will significantly change how controllers are disposed.  The only thing that matters is that it gets disposed, and I doubt MS will stop disposing of the controller.  I think your concerns are a bit on the paranoid side.

Comment: When it comes to Microsoft and potential leaks I rather stay on the paranoid side and get rid of the resources, just to be sure. Better safe than sorry. We aren't talking about hours of work, its just a few lines of code.

Comment: Using that logic, you can't rely on the fact that OnActionExecuted will get called either.  Microsoft could "forget" to do it in a future release.  At least with the Dispose method, the framework is guaranteed to call it at some point, even if the specific MVC implementation has a bug that doesn't call it.

Comment: I guess we can agree that we disagree. I'll keep on coding defensively and that's what I recommend others to do as well. But in the end everybody will do as they think is best and I'm fine witrh that.

Comment: That's my point.  You're *NOT* coding defensively.  If MS introduces a bug that doesn't call OnActionExecuted, your context never gets disposed.  Dispose is the only thing you can count on to eventually get called, even if MVC forgets to dispose of the controller properly.

Comment: I'm also concerned about what happens if you call a child action within your action.  I think your original context would be overwritten, which could result in uncommitted data.

Comment: @MystereMan this is actually a valid concern I didn't think of yet. I don't know if the framework is smart enough to not run through the lifecycle multiple times.